# Are the laws of perspective different depending on the planet we're on?

Tags: optics

Are the laws of perspective different depending on the planet you're on? By that, I am asking if how you calculate the location of a mountain based on several pictures taken around the mountain needs to take into account the size and the curvature of the planet, or the size and curvature have no effect whatsoever. For example, is it different on the moon, or the formulas you use on earth is as valid on the moon as on earth and vice versa with no adjustment needed?

By the way, I am assuming there are no variables to plug into the formula, because I am totally a layman on this.

Answer (score 3):

This is more math than optics, more about surveying than perspective, and it depends on what surveying methods you use.

As part of your surveying method, you need to pick some coordinate system to describe positions of points. For example, if you pick latitude, longitude, and elevation, then your coordinates are tied up with the curvature of the planet's surface. If you use a plumb bob to find vertical, then you're referring to the planet's gravitational field.

But things like vanishing points, triangulation, and the type of [projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) effected by your camera or eye, or employed on your flat charts, have nothing to do with the planet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be the same, you can use Newton's law of universal gravitation on moon, on Jupiter, that's why the laws of physics is coined as "universal law" and natural law, so it must be the same, only in blackhole where laws of physics are totally destroyed, as well as time.

Comment: Hmm, but the variables are different, aren't they? I am not sure if the variables for determining the location of a thing is different on the moon.

Comment: I don't think so, but they should work as they do here.